# Error failed to resolve: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:9.4.0'

Tags: android, google-cast

tried to build a sample project after downloading from github.
But some errors showed up. Others solved but Couldn't resolve above issue mentioned in title.
Cast framework is required for this project but can't find it even after searching in project structure, shows nothing.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: make sure you have installed an updated version of google play services, it might be the issue. just go to SDK manager and check google play services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have set up Google Play Services SDK.

> 1. Start Android Studio
> 2. On the Tools menu, click Android > SDK Manager.
> 3. Update the Android Studio SDK Manager: click SDK Tools, expand Support Repository, select Google Repository, and then click OK.

The latest version of play services is 10.0.1. Under the buid.gradle of your application module, write:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:10.0.1'
    }
```

and click on Sync.